# Reading inputs in smaller, more frequent reads or one larger read

Tags: c++, io

I was working on a C++ tutorial exercise that asked to count the number of words in a file. It got me thinking about the most efficient way to read the inputs. How much more efficient is it really to read the entire file at once than it is to read small chunks (line by line or character by character)?

Comment: Try it and share the results.

Comment: Its not possible to read the entire file at once. However you can read the input file line by line and character by character. This is based on the Buffer reader functions, that reads the input stream of data. So far, you have access to functions such as fopen or fread that reads input stream line by line before processing character by character on each line. The logic is the same, fopen or fread will use a for loop or while loop to process each character at a time before moving to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

The answer changes depending on how you're doing the I/O.

If you're using the POSIX `open`/`read`/`close` family, reading one byte at a time will be excruciating since each byte will cost one system call.

If you're using the C `fopen`/`fread`/`fclose` family or the C++ `iostream` library, reading one byte at a time still isn't great, but it's much better.  These libraries keep an internal buffer and only call `read` when it runs dry.  However, since you're doing something very trivial for each byte, the per-call overhead will still likely dwarf the per-byte processing you actually have to do.  But measure it and see for yourself.

Another option is to simply `mmap` the entire file and just do your logic on that.  You might, or might not, notice a performance difference between `mmap` with and without the `MAP_POPULATE` flag.  Again, you'll have to measure it and see.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method for I/O is to keep the data flowing.

That said, reading one block of 512 characters is faster than 512 reads of 1 character.  Your system may have made optimizations, such as caches, to make reading faster, but you still have the overhead of all those function calls.

There are different methods to keep the I/O flowing:

- Memory mapped file I/O
- Double buffering
- Platform Specific API

Some simple experiments should suffice for demonstration.

Create a vector or array of 1 megabyte.
Start a timer.
Repeat 1000 times:
  Read data into container using 1 read instruction.
End the timer.

Repeat, using a for loop, reading 1,000,000 characters, with 1 read instruction each.

Compare your data.

**Details**
For each request from the hard drive, the following steps are performed (depending on platform optimizations):

- Start hard drive spinning.
- Read filesystem directory.
- Search directory for the filename.
- Get logical position of the byte requested.
- Seek to the given track & sector.
- Read 1 or more sectors of data into hard drive memory.
- Return the requested portion of hard drive memory to the platform.
- Spin down the hard drive.

This is called overhead (except where it reads the sectors).
The object is to get as much data transferred while the hard drive is spinning.  Starting a hard drive takes more time than to keep it spinning.